# Java: Stack with fast lookup

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, stack, graph-theory

The datastructure I'm searching for is a stack which has constant performance on contains().  Currently I'm using my own class for this which manages a HashMap in parallel which stores the frequencies of each entry. When contains() is called, it just returns if the elements frequency in the map is greater than 0.

Is there a prebuilt datastructure for this, optimally in Guava since I'm already using that?
In case there is not, is there a better solution than what I did?

I don't want to manage a set and a stack in parallel inside the class that uses it because in my opinion, it's not a clean design because this clutters the code with more objects and reveals lower levels of abstraction.

In case it helps: It is for a graph algorithm where I want to manage explored vertices in this stack, so that I can backtrack and mark them as *unexplored* in reversed order.

Comment: "I don't want to manage a set and a stack in parallel inside the class that uses it". Are you saying you haven't abstracted the functionality to your own `HashStack` (or something) class? This seems like a trivial problem, and I doubt there's an existing implementation that would be worth adding another dependency.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise, I did exactly that and it works fine.

Comment: No, there is no such built-in data structure. Write your custom class so that the API has only those functions you need. That shouldn't expose lower levels of abstraction.

Comment: So you've abstracted it away cleanly. That's not bad design. That's using minimal effort so you can concentrate on the *actual valuable parts* of your system, i.e. the graph algorithm. The only thing you need to do is to use a `HashSet` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: I thought so too, but I think no. As the stack does not contain unique elements, theres following problem: If element x is contained once and I remove it, then contains should give "false" after that. If x was contained twice, the removal of one of them doesn't change anything. I could make sure the stack only contains unique elements, but then I can't reuse it later for other cases. Also HashSet over HashMap doesn't give me that big of a speedup I think (at least asymptoticially) ?

Comment: Ah yeah, right. Well, then keep the `HashMap`. You can put your code on [Codreview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want to see if there's something to fix with the design, but I wouldn't concentrate on that too much. Your main beef is the graph algorithm.